# "How can you say it" or "How you can say it"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Just a simple question, which one is right?

> How can you say it
>   *or*
>   How you can say it

(It's supposed to be a statement, not a question.)

Comment: The rightness depends upon context, which you have not given.

Answer (score 2):

The right sentence should be `How can you say it?` or  `How do you say it`?, I think that it is more frequently used.

`How you can say it?`is not correct in English grammar.

Comment: It is correct as a subordinate clause; it's not correct as a main clause. _He doesn't know how you can say it_ is grammatical; _*He doesn't know how can you say it_ is ungrammatical.